# Integrate Audio Media Player into website

Tags: java, audio, mp3, media-player

I just wanted to know what frameworks are out there which allow easy audio file streaming in the browser (I only need mp3, to be integrated into a **Java based website**).

I prefer **NON-FLASH** technologies and it should be free / open-source.

I looked at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) so far which just does it via iFrames (so the browser plays the file if he can with any available matching browser plugin, e.g. Quicktime, Windows Media Player, etc.), any other recommendations?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting, new? :

It is called [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/): http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

But I'm still interested in other frameworks, if you know any.

Comment: SoundManager does not play well on the iPhone

Comment: 4 years passed, most likely you found best way. Can you help me? What can you advice about this?

Comment: I'm still using SoundManager2